# Ubuntu restricted extras after install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

what is the Ubuntu restricted extras 
Should installed (Ubuntu restricted extras) after the install ubuntu 12.04 ?

Answer (score 5):

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a software package for the computer operating system Ubuntu that allows the user to install essential software which is not already included due to legal or copyright reasons.

It is a meta-package that installs:

- Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
- Microsoft TrueType core fonts
- Flash plugin
- codecs for common audio and video files

The ubuntu-restricted-extras is a metapackage and has the following dependencies[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras):

```
flashplugin-installer
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
gstreamer0.10-pitfdll
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
icedtea6-plugin
libavcodec-extra-52
libmp4v2-0
ttf-mscorefonts-installer
unrar
```

[**Source**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras)

To install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` from the Ubuntu Software Center, click the below icon:
[image: Install via the software center]

Or via terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

They are media codecs required for playing media files (songs and videos). Without installing it you can't Play songs and videos.

To install it open terminal (Press ctrl+alt+t)
 and Type following command

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Answer (score 0):

if you are newbie you could see that you cant play mo3 file or flash player or rar and such stuffs.

ubuntu restricted extras is a a package that contain all these stuffs that you already used @ windows before