# Install Tahoma font in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, permissions, fonts

When I tried to install the font Tahoma with these commands, I got two errors (permissions denied):

```
$ cabextract -F 'tahoma*ttf' IELPKTH.CAB
IELPKTH.CAB: WARNING; possible 5592 extra bytes at end of file.
Extracting cabinet: IELPKTH.CAB
  extracting tahoma.ttf
tahoma.ttf: Permission denied
  extracting tahomabd.ttf
tahomabd.ttf: Permission denied

$ wget http://download.microsoft.com/download/ie6sp1/finrel/6_sp1/W98NT42KMeXP/EN-US/IELPKTH.CAB
cabextract -F 'tahoma*ttf' IELPKTH.CAB
mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
mv -f tahoma*ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/tahoma*
fc-cache -v
rm -f IELPKTH.CAB
```

Comment: You would probably be better off installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` which includes the core MS .ttf fonts which includes Tahoma. [See this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/199594/ubuntu-restricted-extras-after-install-ubuntu-12-04) for info.

Comment: sorry, have you tried as root?

Comment: @douggro you are wrong, tahoma ist not inside the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package, its only Times New Roman and some other fonts.

Answer (score 8):

You can give try with script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ ! -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/tahoma.ttf -o ! -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/tahomabd.ttf ] &&
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/OldFiles/IELPKTH.CAB &&
cabextract -F 'tahoma*ttf' IELPKTH.CAB &&
mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ &&
mv -f tahoma*ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ &&
chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/tahoma* &&
fc-cache -v &&
rm -f IELPKTH.CAB &&
echo "Installed Tahoma"
```

Answer (score 4):

what you can do is a simple method.

> 1. download [tahoma](https://www.fonts.com/de/font/microsoft-corporation/tahoma) font.
> 2. Then copy that downloaded font and all you have to do is paste it in this folder:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype
```

But since this folder is protected, you will have to open this folder as root. i.e right click and **OPEN AS ROOT**. provide your password and paste it there. THATS ALL...!!!

Comment: @DavidFoerster i) we're not lawyers, if Microsoft has an issue with a very well know page, I'm sure they have the legal muscle to deal with it. ii) Since the [Microsoft page for the  Tahoma font](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=19) actually links directly to the fonts.com page in this answer, I think it's safe to assume that no copyright is being violated and Microsoft is fine with this redistribution.

Comment: @terdon: I agree that Microsoft seems to be fine with distribution in general. However Fontpalace.com is not Fonts.com and distributes the font without a license *notice* (the page says “License: Unknown”); I doubt that the distribution is still legal under that circumstance.

Comment: I circumvented the issue by editing the answer to link to the Font.com page instead. That should resolve it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I stand corrected, I thought the link was already pointing to fonts.com. Sorry. However, it really isn't our job to deal with copyright issues. And downvoting for that reason seems strange to say the least.

Comment: From $49 ?  You have to be kidding.... I used the script, in the other answer, for free!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. You have to do a "sudo" and issue the command one by one :

```
$ wget http://download.microsoft.com/download/ie6sp1/finrel/
$ cabextract -F 'tahoma*ttf' IELPKTH.CAB
$ sudo mv -f tahoma*ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
$ chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/tahoma*
$ fc-cache -v
$ rm -f IELPKTH.CAB
```

Comment: -1 That won't work because the `cabextract` command fails. Nothing related to `sudo`.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/ie6sp1/finrel/ returns 404

Answer (score 0):

[Download Tahoma.](https://www.wfonts.com/font/tahoma)

Right click and "Open With Fonts".

[image: Open With Fonts]

When it opens click on Install.

[image: Install]

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You need a license to use Tahoma font.

If you don't need the original font, the Wine project includes a free and open-source replacement font `wine-tahoma` (and `wine-tahoma-bold`) released under GNU Lesser General Public License designed to have identical metrics to the Tahoma font.

It can easily be installed using this script:

```
wget https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/ee5a1a4222dd43c8b4af5c99ed72b3fc/raw/ttf-wine-tahoma-installer.sh -q -O - | sudo bash
```